# Change v alue of a new record's field according to a previous record

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Deadline is coming and I still have a problem with one thing on my crm2011 project. 
Here is what I've done: I created two custom entities based on contract and contractdetail entities.

Here is what I need: when a contractdetail record is set to inactive and its "allotmentsremaining" < 0 then when adding a new contractdetail, the default "allotmentsremaining" and "allotmentsused" values should change.

Here is an example: I have a contractdetail record set to inactive with an "allotmentsremaining" value of -15. When I create a new record, the "allotmentsused" should be set to 15.

What are the solutions? Would you happen to have sample code for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably want to use a plugin that runs on (pre)create of a contractdetail record.

When the contractdetail record is created the plugin would fire and would go to the parent contract record, find all the contractdetail children. Locate the latest contract detail child if it exists. If it is inactive or active, take action to set the default values on the new contract detail record being created.

It's assumed that you have an action to do if no child is found, ie default-default values, if a child is found there are values to set if its active or inactive. And that you only care about the latest child. If you have more than one child record which one should it take into account.

This could be done via workflow, or a custom workflow assembly, Or even javascript through the Rest End Point using OData but a plugin seems the easiest and most robust solution in your case.

Link on how to write a plugin and compile the
[Plugin Registration Tool needed for plugins and a quick tutorial](http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/plugins-in-crm-2011/)